# Searching for 'exposure triangle' doesn't find the question 'What is the "exposure triangle"?'

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

If I [search for exposure triangle](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=exposure+triangle), I get 3 questions (none of which really relate to the exposure triangle.)

Seems to me like [What is the "exposure triangle"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle) should show up as one of the results.

It looks like the search feature is interpreting exposure as a tag, as the right column says "3 search results for posts containing **triangle** tagged with [exposure]"

Comment: I just added the tag "exposure" to that question, which should help the specific case, but clearly there's a bug. Also, clearly, I need to write up my rant on that subject. :)

Answer (score 2):

the implied tag in that search is getting mapped to [exposure](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exposure).

We automatically do this for the top N tags on a site. Therefore when you search for

> exposure triangle

you are actually de-facto searching for

> [exposure] triangle

Because that's the 14th most used tag on the site.

edit: Our threshold for this "search word to tag" conversion is 25 questions minimum, which may be too low since we totally rewrote search. I went ahead and increased it to 100 questions minimum.

Comment: What a strange feature! Now I start to understand why I don't seem to get anything useful whenever I try to use the search tool. I usually just give up and use google (with something like `site:xxx.stackexchange.com`) instead, and then get the expected results...

Comment: @jukka a huge proportion of searches on Stack Overflow were for the word "c#". What kind of results do you think they got? Also before "giving up" in such dramatic fashion, why not visit http://photo.stackexchange.com/search and use the Google option there on that page? (just press enter in the search box to get to that page)

Comment: Thanks, it is good to know that there is a simpler way to use Google search on SE sites!

Comment: Is there no way to quote the search terms or designate otherwise to prevent some surprises like this?

Comment: @rfu try putting a plus in front of each word, or putting each word in quotes.